# What are the main beliefs/themes of the Prosperity Gospel and which are the current prominent groups and their pastors?

Tags: belief, prosperity-gospel

What are the main beliefs/themes of the Prosperity Gospel?

And which are the current prominent groups and their pastors?

Comment: It would probably be good to specifically ask for those who self identify as prosperity teachers... for many it is a pejorative label that would be rejected (even if it would be justified).

Comment: @curiousdannii Please go ahead and edit and I will review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main premise of the prosperity doctrine is that the believer is in total control of his life and the wealth and health that he has or doesn't have is in direct correlation to the words he speaks. The main proponents of this doctrine are leaders such as: Kenneth Hagan Jr; Kenneth Copeland; Joel Osteen; Norvel Hayes; Derrick Prince...

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: This answer would be better if you [edit] in a source or two.